# Best practice for dealing with data classes

Tags: kotlin, data-class

It seems like a very simple and trivial question, but how do you deal with data classes where the attributes can change over time?
I know data classes should only contain immutable attributes, but what to do if it's necessary that they are mutable.

The Todo data class reflects an entry in a todo list. As such an entry can be reformulated or change from "not done" to "done", the values must or should be changeable.
How would such a thing be handled correctly?

First Approach:
Values are declared as var and are publicly accessible.
The values are changed directly by another class

```
data class Todo (
    var description: String,
    var isDone: Boolean
)
class TodoList (
    val entries: MutableList<Todo> = mutableListOf()
) {
    fun setTodoDone(entry: Todo) { entries[entries.indexOf(entry)].isDone = true }
    fun updateDesc(entry: Todo, desc: String) { 
        entries[entries.indexOf(entry)].description = desc 
    }
}
```

Second Approach:
Values are assigned during initialisation.
The values cannot be accessed directly, but are accessed via backing properties.
Changes to the values are monitored by calling corresponding methods within the data class.

```
data class Todo2 (
    private var _description: String,
    private var _isDone: Boolean
) {
    val description: String
        get() = _description

    val isDone: Boolean
        get() = _isDone

    fun setDone() { _isDone = true }
    fun updateDescription(desc: String) { _description = desc }
}

class TodoList2 (
    val entries: MutableList<Todo2> = mutableListOf()
) {
    fun setTodoDone(entry: Todo2) = entry.setDone()
    fun updateDesc(entry: Todo2, desc: String) = entry.updateDescription(desc)
}
```

Third Approach:
The values of the data class remain unchanged.
Changes to the entries are made via a copy of the entries, which are saved in modified form.

```
data class Todo3 (
    val description: String,
    val isDone: Boolean
)

class TodoList3 (
    val entries: MutableList<Todo3> = mutableListOf()
) {
    fun setTodoDone(entry: Todo3) {
        entries[entries.indexOf(entry)] = entry.copy(isDone = true)
    }
    fun updateDesc(entry: Todo3, desc: String) {
        entries[entries.indexOf(entry)] = entry.copy(description = desc)
    }
}
```

Is one of this approaches correct, or should such a problem be solved a completelly other way like using a normal class instad of a data class?
Thaks for your reply :-D

Comment: The concepts of data class and immutability are orthogonal. You should favour immutability most of the time, irrespective of whether it's a data class or a normal class. You should use a data class if you want the compiler to generate `equals` and `hashCode` for you, irrespective of whether you want its properties to be immutable or not.

Comment: In your particular case I don't see anything wrong with your first approach, but it is a matter of opinion and unfortunately opinions are not considered suitable for StackOverflow. This means your question might be closed for this reason, but it won't be me that votes for closure, as I think opinions _can_ be useful (as long as they don't end up in a flame war).

Comment: One word of warning though: if you add Todo items into a `HashMap`, `HashSet`, `LinkedHashMap` (such as that created by `mapOf`) etc. then you'd better make them immutable, otherwise you'd get weird behaviour.

Comment: Having a mutable class (or list) that represents data is reaching the point of being an anti-pattern, because majority of "modern" design patterns and built in libraries (`LiveData`, `Flows` even compose) depend on having data flow down in one direction and will just misbehave and break when you mutate and re-emit the same object. So I'd recommend having them immutable and use generated `.copy()` method of data class to create updated copies instead.

Comment: Mutable classes are highly useful in performance critical code. I use them in games and OpenGL stuff. But on Android, they break the behavior of LiveData, StateFlow, State, and RecyclerView’s ListAdapter.

Comment: Where downstream uses of a class might expect immutability (e.g `Set` or `LiveData`) or where the codebase is big / lots of developers, then I go for immutability and provide clear functions to manage attribute alterations (`TodoList3`).  But if your `ToDo` is an interface/etc then `.copy()` quickly gets unwieldy as you cannot write common code since `.copy()` must operate on concrete classes.  In those cases I then go for `var`.